# Property detection: Using 'in' versus trying to access property

Tags: javascript

Have to mention: I know a bit JavaScript but I'm not very deep into it.

Always considered this the correct way to check if a property is available on an object:

```
if (window.console) {
  // doSomething
}
```

Yesterday I've seen code in which this technique was used:

```
if ('console' in window) {
  // doSomething
}
```

Are both techniques equivalent? Or do they distinguish?

Comment: Try doing a `window.console = false;` and then run both your constructs. See what happens -- https://jsfiddle.net/abhitalks/xmohL5wr/

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Nope. They have a difference.

First one checks if the value of `window.console` is Truthy and the second one checks of the `console` property exists in `window`.

Let's say you create a variable like this.

```
window.myName = "";
```

Now, `if (window.MyName)` will fail to satisfy the condition, as empty strings are Falsy in JavaScript.

```
console.log(Boolean(window.myName)); // false
```

But `if ("myName" in window)` will satisfy the condition, as `myName` is a property of `window` object.

```
console.log(Boolean("myName" in window)); // true
```

---

**Note:** `in` operator will return `true` even if the property being tested is somewhere in the prototype hierarchy. For example,

```
console.log("toString" in {});  // true
```

It returns `true` because the object `{}` inherits the method `toString`.

If you want to make sure that the property exists on the object itself, then you should use [`Object.prototype.hasOwnProperty`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/hasOwnProperty), like this

```
console.log({}.hasOwnProperty("toString")); // false
```

Comment: Okay. In case of the first one: If console doesn't exist it returns undefined == falsy value. So it doesn't enter the if-block. Then the usage of "in" would be cleaner way?

Comment: @bo256 If you really want to check if a property exists or not, then you should go for `in` operator.

Answer (score 4):

No. They have a difference.

When using the `in` operator, you check if the property is specified in the given object and not it's value. For example:

```
var obj = { foo: undefined }
obj.foo !== undefined;  // false
'foo' in obj;           // true
```

Hope It Helps

Answer (score 1):

In your case it's equivalent. When you use *in* operator, it looks that property exisits in object. And when you use *if (window.console)* it looks that window.console is a truth value.

Answer (score 1):

When you say `window.console` it will check for the property `console` in `window` object.I does not consider weather `console` property is own property of window object or it is inherited from parent.

On the other side in `console in window`, the **in** will make sure property is exist as own property of window object and not inherited from parent.

Comment: See @thefourtheye answer